# jQuery plugin not loading?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm trying to use the rounded corners demo for jQuery (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/corners), but I'm getting an error in both Firefox and IE when it tries to run.

The code below shows what I'm trying to do, the error is '$(".Section").corners is not a function'.  The page is definitely loading jquery, but not loading the corners plugin.

Anyone know why this is throwing an error?

```
<script src="../../Content/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Content/Scripts/jquery.corners.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.Section').corners();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wich corner script are you using?

Comment: Can you access the corners.js file from you browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a page to load jQuery Corners to see if I could get it to work at all:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .Section {
        border-color: #000;
        border-width: medium;
        border-style: solid;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.corners.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.Section').corners();
        });
    </script>
    <title>Corners</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p class="Section">
    Here is some text in my soon to be rounded corner paragraph.
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What I found in my tests is that the Corners plugin loaded, but using jQuery 1.4.4 and testing with Chrome 8.0.552.224, Safari 5.0.3, Firefox 3.6.13, and Internet Explorer 8 that only Safari and Fireefox showed the corners.  Chrome produced CSS errors in the console, IE just ignored the JavaScript.  With that in mind, I recommend you give [CSS3 PIE a try for IE](http://css3pie.com/) and use a bit of combo CSS for your other elements:

```
<style type="text/css">
.Section {
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}       
</style>
```

The CSS above is from an example produced [in a blog post by Jon Raasch](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers).

Comment: I couldn't figure out exactly why the corners script wasn't working, but i was able to get this working in FF and IE. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DLeh You were able to get what working? The Jquery Plugin or the corners mentioned in this answer?

Answer (score 5):

Use the Net panel in Firebug (or equivalent developer tools) and ensure the script is being loaded first of all. If not, you should see it return a 404 status for its line item in the Net panel.

Comment: I'm getting a 200 OK for the corners script and the jquery script

Answer (score 2):

I've run through your code and I don't see what the problem is. You could try this code inside your $(document).ready and see what it returns:

```
alert(typeof jQuery().corners)
```

If it alerts "function" then you know corners is loading. If it alerts "undefined" then it's not loading and you can track down that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was using same library and had same problem, what i did was.

copy paste whole code of `corner.js` library before your document.ready code and check is it started working or not?

if not mean `corner.js` should be downloaded again.

Answer (score -2):

should be `$('.Section').corner();`  not `$('.Section').corners()`

this only applies if you using the "jQuery corner plugin"